# Is it possible to detect file overwriting using Apache Commons IO?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm using Apache's `FileAlterationMonitor` to monitor a specific directory in my project, and I was wondering if there is a way to monitor file overwriting too, since otherwise I'd have to delete a file, wait the monitor to perform a check to detect the file was deleted, and then write the file again to behave correctly

Comment: Can't you switch to NIO/2 and its `WatchService`?

Comment: `WatchService` works, but I can't use it in my application for other reasons...

Answer (score 2):

make use of `onFileChange` hook provided by `FileAlterationListener`

```
@Override
public void onFileChange(File file) {
    System.out.println("File got changed "+ file);
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but it does nothing, neither overwriting nor explicitly deleting and moving again

Comment: thats strange. I would suggest you to run FileAlterationObserver in a ever running thread

Comment: that's exactly what I am doing